# Including jQuery in Wordpress doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm currently trying to run a jQuery script into my Wordpress website. The problem is I don't see nothing, but when I try to execute a simple javascript, it works.

I've created this simple script called *custom_script.js* :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery("#test-script").html("jQuery says Hello World");
});
```

With its relative div inside my html page:

```
<div id="test-script"></div>
```

This script was uploaded into the folder inside the *js* folder, and into *functions.php* file I've added the *enqueue_script()* method inside a function which already has others similar (the lines in bold are the one I've added):

```
function nectar_register_js() { 

    global $options;

    if (!is_admin()) { 

        // Register 
        wp_register_script('modernizer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/modernizr.js', 'jquery', '2.6.2');
        wp_register_script('respond', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/respond.js', 'jquery', '1.1', TRUE);
        wp_register_script('superfish', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/superfish.js', 'jquery', '1.4.8', TRUE);
        wp_register_script('respond', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/respond.js', 'jquery', '1.1',TRUE);
        wp_register_script('orbit', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/orbit.js', 'jquery', '1.4', TRUE);
        wp_register_script('nicescroll', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/nicescroll.js', 'jquery', '3.5.4' ,TRUE);
        wp_register_script('sticky', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/sticky.js', 'jquery', '1.0', TRUE);
        wp_register_script('nectar_prettyPhoto', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/prettyPhoto.js', 'jquery', '5.5.4', TRUE);
        wp_register_script('nectar_parallax', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/parallax.js', 'jquery', '1.0', TRUE);
        wp_register_script('isotope', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/isotope.min.js', 'jquery', '2.0' ,TRUE);
        wp_register_script('nectarSlider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/nectar-slider.js', 'jquery', '5.5.4', TRUE);
        wp_register_script('iosSlider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.iosslider.min.js', 'jquery', '5.5.4', TRUE);
        wp_register_script('ajaxify', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajaxify.js', 'jquery', '5.5.4', TRUE);
        **wp_register_script('custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js', 'jquery');**

        if ( floatval(get_bloginfo('version')) < "3.6" ) {
            wp_register_script('jplayer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jplayer.min.js', 'jquery', '2.1', TRUE);
        }
        wp_register_script('nectarFrontend', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/init.js', array('jquery', 'superfish'), '5.5.4', TRUE);

        // Dequeue
        wp_dequeue_script( 'prettyPhoto' );



        // Enqueue
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('modernizer');
        wp_enqueue_script('superfish'); 
        wp_enqueue_script('respond');
        **wp_enqueue_script('custom_script');**
        if(!empty($options['smooth-scrolling']) && $options['smooth-scrolling'] == '1') wp_enqueue_script('nicescroll');
        wp_enqueue_script('sticky'); 
        wp_enqueue_script('nectar_prettyPhoto');
        wp_enqueue_script('isotope');
        if ( floatval(get_bloginfo('version')) < "3.6" ) {
            wp_enqueue_script('jplayer');
        }

        wp_enqueue_script('nectarFrontend');

        $transition_method = (!empty($options['transition-method'])) ? $options['transition-method'] : 'ajax';
        if(!empty($options['ajax-page-loading']) && $options['ajax-page-loading'] == '1' && $transition_method == 'ajax') {
            wp_enqueue_script('nectarSlider');
            wp_enqueue_script('ajaxify');
        }



    }
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'nectar_register_js');
```

The problem is I don't see the new text inside the specific div tag. What am I missing? Thank you so much. (For your information, the theme I am using is called Salient)

Comment: Did you check your console for errors?

Comment: Yes, it says that:

http://imgur.com/50PM2kn .

The problem is I don't have the direct access to the homepage code since it's created by some wordpress editors and the result is not a classic html.

Comment: From that console log image that you sent, I could see all requests are returning 404 file not found since you have a prefix of `wp` infront of `wp-includes` directory. I guess you need to get rid of `wp` to overcome this issue.

Comment: How can I accomplish this? The code is autogenerated, I can't see that requests from the code view.

Comment: Aside this, jQuery works if I try to execute some javascript inserted directly in that autogenerated code.

Comment: Check out your database, the table **wp_options** the **first** and **secound** line, check if the url has no a `/wp/` on the end.

Comment: Or else, try changing all your occurrences of `get_template_directory_uri()` in your code (pasted above) to `plugins_url()`

Comment: @DavidR It doesn't change nothing, sorry. But the solution proposed by ClaudioB works: the errors are gone but into the div tag I still can't see the result of the jquery script previously mentioned.

Comment: Ohh. Sorry about that.. Follow @ClaudioB. suggestion then! :-)

Comment: @DavidR Yes, thank you so much anyway, I'll try to understand why it doesn't load from the file then :-)

Comment: Is there something on console?

Comment: Nothing. In addition to this, if I go to the js folder, I don't see the *custom_script.js* file. This is strange.

Comment: Make sure that the file is being called, and try that:
`jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $("#test-script").html("jQuery says Hello World");
});`

Comment: I've called the wrong file, thank you so much!